# Reducing amount of clicks to create Publishing Page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: development, 2007, publishing-page, publishing-site

I have a customer who is using the MOSS 2007 WCM Publishing Site.

To create a page in this environment you need to:

- Select  Site Settings | Create Page
- Fill in:

  - Title
  - page url
  - select a page layout
- Click Add
- Enter content
- Click Submit for Approval

Has anyone done anything around this flow to create a page:

- Click Create Page (automatically knows what Page Layout to pick and hides these options)
- Fill in:

  - Title
  - Page URL
- Click Add
- Enter Content
- Click Submit for Approval

**Upload Images**
Also a reduced amount of clicks for uploading an image to a page field e.g. click browse straight from page layout, select image off local file system and it is uploaded into Site Collection Images and automatically set as page field url.

Comment: @jthake: Regarding upload images, I asked a similar question relating to a simpler experience for copy/paste: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/857/copy-and-paste-for-images-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to restrict the number of page layouts that can be used when creating new pages in a certain site. By restricting this number to one you are essentially fixing the layout to a particular type. The page layout will still be visible to a user when the are creating a page, but they can't change to another - hence reducing the number of clicks.

To do this, go to site settings, and under the Look and Feel section click the *Page layouts and site templates* link. From the following page you can choose which page layouts are available when creating a new page.

Comment: Thanks Glyn, I did actually do this, in fact programmatically as part of set up of site. Obviosly this is all a lot slicker in #SP2010 ;-) but these guys won't be on that for a while.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this is to use list-based content instead.  (Turn the paradigm on it's side, at least!)  This way, you get full content management features for each item, and you can have a single page which "publishes" everything.  This page just has a DVWP (or two or three) which makes it totally dynamic.  By passing the key info on the Query String to the page, you have "bookmarkable" pages, too.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by 'list-based content'? so you aren't using 'create page' with page layouts and just use the New List Item stuff instead and then one page via query string dynamically builds content with querystring id? Why would you do this over publishing pages? what is the advantage?

Comment: To me there are clear advantages.  Datasheet view for editing is one obvious one: a quick way to change a large number of "pages".  Since the content is in list items, you have other possibilities for its use, like dashboards, cross-"page" rollups, etc. My question back would be 'What's the advantage of "WCM" over "CM"'?